# How to save data in mongodb express by referring another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have created the following `User` schema

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fullName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: true,
    },
    department: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Department",
      required: true,
    },
  },
});
```

and my `Department` schema looks like the following

```
const DepartmentSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      desc: "Description.",
      type: String,
    },
  },
  {
    strict: true,
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: { createdAt: "createdAt", updatedAt: "updatedAt" },
  });
```

Now I'm able to create departments and all is working well in Postman and also my Angular application. But while creating `User` it only saves the department ID that I've selected or added in my form. This is the data that I've tried to create

```
user = {
  department: "5f806be7c9a3c02c7c61f9f1"
  fullName: "John Joshua"
}
```

and my create route controller looks like this

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    fullName: req.body.fullName,
    department: req.body.department,
  });

  try {
    const errors = validationResult(req); // I've used express validator here
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
      return;
    }
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.json(savedUser); // Here I was expecting to return the new saved user with Department details
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

So my response is all good and working well but `department` only contains the `ID` with nothing more.

How can I send a response data with Department details? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `await savedUser.populate('department');` assuming you have a collection `Departments` with a document that has that id.

Comment: @ippi does it also save the new user?

Comment: It's normal that you only store the id to the department, and with your current schema, mongoose will discard everything but the object-id. Then every time you need the department, you populate the field before sending it to the user.

Comment: Your other option is to store a "sub-document copy" of the department, but then if the original department changes, then the data stored in the user will not be updated.

Comment: Okay, will try that soon and thanks :)